# Finding final velocity in inelastic collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Information: In a   shipping    company distribution    center, an  open    cart    of  mass    49.0-kg is  rolling to
the left    at  a   speed   of  5.40-m/s    (see    the figure).    You can ignore  friction    between the 
cart    and the floor.  A   17.0-kg package slides  down    a   chute   that    is  inclined    at  37-deg
from    the horizontal  and leaves  the end of  the chute   with    a   speed   of  3.40-m/s.   The 
package lands   in  the cart    and they    roll    off together.

If  the lower   end of  the chute   is  a   vertical    distance    of  4.00-m  above   the bottom
of  the cart,   what    is  the speed   of  the package just    before  it  lands   in  the cart?

Question: What  is  the final   speed   of  the cart?

Equations used:

(1) K$_1$ + U$_1$ + W$_{other}$  = K$_2$ + U$_2$ and for the elastic collision

(2)m$_b$v$_b$+m$_c$v$_c$ = v$_{final}$(m$_b$+m$_c$)

Work: From equation (1). v$_{final}$ = $\sqrt{v^2 + 2gh}$; v$_{final}$ = $9.48 \frac{m}{s}$

To find the x component of the speed it is v$_{final}$ $\cos(\theta)$; v$_x$= $7.51\frac{m}{s}$

Finally for the final speed of both you have from equation (2) you have

v$_{final}$= $\frac{17kg*7.51m/s + 49kg*-5.40m/s}{17kg+49kg}$ = $-2.06m/s$

Issue: With the final velocity, I seem to be getting the right answer. I know the $9.48m/s$ is correct, but for some reason my velocity final after collision is wrong. The correct answer is $-3.31m/s$. I dont know where my problem is though with this. I feel the problem may lie in the v$_{final}$ $\cos(\theta)$; v$_x$= $7.51\frac{m}{s}$. Any thoughts on what the problem may be? As far as I am aware I need to use the speed the box has as it falls the 4 meters and into the cart and the x component of that.

Comment: The horizontal component of the speed must be the same as it leaves the chute and as it lands - the angle is no longer 37 degrees though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compute the final velocity of the parcel you have forgotten that it's no longer traveling at 37 degrees - that was the angle at the end of the chute.

While it drops, the horizontal component of velocity doesn't change - it is still $3.4\cdot \cos 37° = 2.71 m/s$. With that, you should be able to solve this.